# How to deny access to a route for logged user?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I want to deny access of the signup/signin route for logged user directly in the access_controls of security.yaml

Anyone know how to do it cause in the documentation? I didn't see stuff like that.

current access_controls :

```
access_control:

    - { path: ^/signin$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/signup$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
    - { path: ^/product$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can add an access_control allowed only if user has not role ROLE_USER in your security.yaml :

```
    - { path: ^/sign(up|in), allow_if: "not has_role('ROLE_USER')" }
```

You have to add any access_denied_url

```
    access_denied_url: /access-denied
```

And add a controller action with route /access-denied that redirect user to route Login if not logged and to profil page if logged :

```
/**
 * @Route("/access-denied", name="app_access_denied")
 */
public function accessDenied()
{
    if ( $this->getUser() ) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_user_home');
    }

    return $this->redirectToRoute('app_login');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Symfony 5.3+

> The IS_ANONYMOUS and IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY attributes are deprecated since Symfony 5.3.

To ensure allowing access to a path only for anonymous user (not authenticated) you can use the `is_authenticated()` method.

@see https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/expressions.html

This expression can be used into a controller or directly in the `access_control` directive in your `security.yaml`:

```yaml
# security.yaml

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/register, allow_if: "!is_authenticated()" }
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to create an **EventSubscriber** on **AccessDeniedHttpException**
You also need to put those lines on your **security.yaml** :

```
- { path: ^/route, roles: IS_ANONYMOUS}
```

This EventSubscriber catch the access denied and the name of the route the user try to access, like that you can redirect the user where you want depending the route he try to access.

To create an event subscriber on symfony : [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-subscriber)

> Don't forget to subscribe the AccessDeniedHttpException event to your EventSubscriber

The AccessDeniedHttpException() method you put in your subscriber :

```
public function AccessDeniedHttpException(KernelEvent $event) {
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    $lastUrl = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(),'main');
    $currentRoute = $event->getRequest()->attributes->get('_route');
    $redirectUrl = $this->handleRedirect($currentRoute, $request, $lastUrl);
    $response  = new RedirectResponse($redirectUrl);
    $event->setResponse($response);
}
```

handleRedirect is my own method you can create your own to redirect user as you want too